Gradle uses old JAVA_HOME value after JDK upgrade
problem occur after added SH1 signingReport. I was update jdk-17 to jdk 21 but flutter doctor -v still shows old jdk. try many ways but unable to figure exact solution. i already reinstall Android studio, update:gradle 8.5,flutter and dart sdk. can anyone help me out.....
**here is flutter doctor -v **
C:\Users\Khurshid Computers>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011], locale en-PK)
• Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 603104015d (10 days ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
• Engine revision db49896cf2
• Dart version 3.5.4
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\AndroidSDK
• Platform android-34, build-tools 35.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\AndroidSDK
• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Khurshid Computers\AppData\Local\Android
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot" \bin\java
X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.12.7text-hotspot" \bin\java to determine the version
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.4)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35312.102
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
[√] VS Code (version 1.95.0)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Khurshid Computers\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.98.0
[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.92
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.56
[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

on windows click start button, type env, chose Edit system variables for your account, set change JAVA_HOME, edit PATH

see https://youtu.be/OQQC5AScOk4

still some same error

C:\Users\Khurshid Computers>flutter doctor --android-licenses
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\AndroidSDK\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited
code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for detailed instructions.

(1) you set it to eclipae home of IDE Java will be in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21 if u used Oracle or openjdk java. (2) try to use a folder without spaces like  c:\data\projects for your own projects

restart ur computer after u set the java home, make sure to remove it from system properties or set both to same path, you can also over ride Java home per project inside IDE, really need to look around and find the places

Please don't use comments to clarify. Code is hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.
